# Как получить тело ответа HttpClient HttpPost

Tags: java, http, javafx, httpclient

```
MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
ContentType fileContentType = ContentType.create("image/jpeg");
String fileName = file.getName();
builder.addBinaryBody("images_file", file, fileContentType, fileName);

HttpEntity entity = builder.build();

HttpPost request = new HttpPost(urlString+params);
request.setEntity(entity);

HttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
System.out.println(client. );
System.out.println(response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    ...
    ResponseHandler<String> handler = new BasicResponseHandler();
    String body = handler.handleResponse(response);
    int code = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
```

Comment: Это-о ответ или кусок вопроса? Кстати, в чём вопрос заключается?

Comment: Это ответ, а вопрос вы можете прочесть в заголовке

Comment: Странный вопрос и ответ.. без описания.. так можно мануал весь перекопировать по ЯП))